# Generic parameter does not have matching annotations in .NET 8 AOT

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-8.0, native-aot

I have a helper method that returns a list of public static readonly fields of a type:

```
public static ReadOnlyCollection<T> GetFields<T>()
    where T : class
{
    return typeof(T).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
        .Where(x => x.IsInitOnly && x.FieldType == typeof(T))
        .Select(x => (T)x.GetValue(null))
        .ToList().AsReadOnly();
}
```

When I convert my project to .NET 8 AOT, I'm getting the following error:

> error IL2090: 'this' argument does not satisfy
> 'DynamicallyAccessedMemberTypes.PublicFields' in call to
> 'System.Type.GetFields(BindingFlags)'. The generic parameter 'T' of
> 'path\to\helper\GetFields()' does not have matching annotations.
> The source value must declare at least the same requirements as those
> declared on the target location it is assigned to.

How can I fix this error? The helper method is called by unit tests only to ensure constant fields in specific classes are unique and follow certain syntax conventions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark the generic parameter with [`DynamicallyAccessedMembersAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.dynamicallyaccessedmembersattribute?view=net-8.0) (passing corresponding value to `memberTypes` parameter):

```
public static ReadOnlyCollection<T> GetFields<
    [DynamicallyAccessedMembers(DynamicallyAccessedMemberTypes.PublicFields)]
    T>()
    where T : class
{
    // ...
}
```